# Blur offset artifacts

Tags: hlsl, blur

I have simple blur shader which I calculate offsets in:

Piece of vertex shader:

```
output.texCoord1 = input.tex + float2( texelSize * -4.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord12 = input.tex + float2( texelSize * -3.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord13 = input.tex + float2( texelSize * -2.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord14 = input.tex + float2( -texelSize, 0.0f );
output.texCoord15 = input.tex + float2( 0.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord16 = input.tex + float2( texelSize, 0.0f );
output.texCoord17 = input.tex + float2( texelSize *  2.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord18 = input.tex + float2( texelSize *  3.0f, 0.0f );
output.texCoord19 = input.tex + float2( texelSize *  4.0f, 0.0f );
```

However with this manner I have artifacts on the sides of the screen:

[image: Screenshot]

I know that it occurs because when the offset goes out from the right it takes pixels from the left appropriately.

So my question is: how is the "standard" way to deal with this? I was trying to saturate() all of the values assigned to output.texCoordX, it removes the artifacts in 95%, but it makes my blur much weaker and with strange sharper edges ("roll my log and I will roll yours"?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't setting your texture's edge mode to clamp (instead of repeat) solve this issue?

Comment: oh my god that was so easy, I just have forgotten that sampler field, thank you